# Copy Clone with mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I need to create a wpf application with 2 buttons in a homework. one of the buttons is "copy" and the other is "clone". When i press the copy button, it should copy the information in the textboxes on the screen and create a new textbox and write it into it. When we press the clone button, it should copy the information in the same way and write it into a new textbox, but this time if I try to change the value in the cloned textboxes, it should change in all value in cloned textboxes. Does anyone know an example where I can learn the cloning part?

Comment: You will need to dynamically create a textbox, add it to the window, and set its text to a copy of the text from the other textbox. Google for "wpf dynamically create controls" to find out how to dynamically add controls to a WPF window.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, however I guess the gist is, that clone creates a new textbox with the same datacontext as the original, while copy gets its own datacontext (provided this is done with mvvm - do you really have to create the application using mvvm?). Do you have problems with databinding in general, the dynamic creation of textboxes,... -  or more specifically, can you specify where exactly your problem is?

Comment: @RolandDeschain  The reason for mvvm is to make task a little more difficult and to check my information. I know I have to do it using "reference type" and "value type". When I say copy, a new view should be created and a new object should be created for the textbox inside. when I say clone, it should create a new view but have a reference to the value of other textboxes.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I am using reactive UI for "data binding". so I don't have a problem with the binding part. I know how to create a new window when I press the button, but I don't know how to write the data structure in the cloning part.

Comment: Never worked with reactive UI. However what I meant, was that if you use MVVM actually you don't need to worry about copying by value or reference. Simply create a new Textbox in if it was created by copying, bind it to a new string (which you initialize with the content from the original) and if it was created via the clone button, bind it to the original string.

Comment: I would define the textboxes as a datatemplate matching a viewmodel by datatype. Call that a textviewmodel. A viewmodel is a class and hence a reference type. That viewmodel would be exposed from a property of a parent viewmodel. I could then new up a textviewmodel and copy values to it's properties or i could just set it to an existing instance of textviewmodel. In the latter case you've literally got the same object your textboxes are binding to - change one value and all change.  I have no idea if that satisfies your teacher. I wouldn't new up any controls.

Comment: @Andy I understand what you mean. but this program should be able to do this not once, several times, one after the other. so i need to build something that can be cloned 3-4 times in a row. Additionally, I need to figure out how to create a new textbox or a new Window page when I press the "clone/copy" buttons.

Comment: So you have to be able to make a copy of a clone, clone of a copy, clone of a clone and a copy of a copy as often as you want?

Comment: You can have any number of parent viewmodels with the same instance of textviewmodel. Or new instances. There's no "just once"  limit to what i described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was interested so I thought I give it a try and make a sample program myself.
I can't give you my code to just copy, but here is some basic structure that worked for me:

**View:**

- A ListBox with Textbox as Itemtemplate. ItemSource is bound to a `ObservableCollection<StringModel> StringList` in the ViewModel, which I will come to later. SelectedItem is Bound to a single `StringModel SelectedString` instance in the ViewModel
- Clone Button
- Copy Button
- In the code behind (or wherever you want) simply set up your ViewModel as datacontext and the firing of the corresponding functions in the ViewModel, in case the buttons are pressed (next point)

**StringModel**
This is  as simple as it gets, a wrapper class around a string, in order to A) pass as reference and B) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Notice the second constructer taking in a string as argument.

```
public class StringModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string stringValue;

    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { SetProperty<string>(ref stringValue, value); }
    }


    public StringModel(){ }

    public StringModel(string value)
    {
        StringValue = value;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**
This class simply holds the Collection mentioned above as well as the property of the currently selected item. Additionally we have two functions corresponding to the buttons:

```
public void AddCopy()
{
    if (SelectedString == null)
        return;

    StringList.Add(new StringModel(SelectedString.StringValue));
}

public void AddClone()
{
    if (SelectedString == null)
        return;
    StringList.Add(SelectedString);
}
```

As you can see, since your `StringModel` is now a separate class, you can pass it by reference, or in case of copying, simply create a new one with the string content.

Obviously there are some additional checks to be make (hint: null pointer exception with the ObservableCollection, INotifyPropertyChanged implementation of ViewModel Properties), but this should get you started. Ask away if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and for giving me some ideas. A lot of points are still too dark for me but I have to find a way somehow. Thank you again i will try to use your system

Comment: @JuniorKS OK, let me know if you need help.

Comment: I'm a very bad software developer. I couldn't finish the project

Comment: I created the project but there are a lot of errors

Comment: @JuniorKS Can you share the project (Github or similar)? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/mGKScoder/CopyCloneTest-3 here is. main problems. I have 2 views in my project. one is mainwindow and the other is usercontrol. Every time I click the copy or clone buttons, I want the usercontrol to add to the main window. but somehow I can't add usercontrol to mainwindow in mvvm style. The other problem is that I have two vms, one for usercontrol and other is main. I want to take the values to come from here and send them to mainviewmodel. I try to get the result from there and send it back again. but i guess i made logical mistakes

Comment: @JuniorKS I think your repo is private. I can't access it. Anyway, obviously if you have to vms the somehow need to know about each other.

Comment: thank you for everything but now i lost my chance.